# WPF ScrollBar not showing up on Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, scrollviewer

Here is my Grid, no matter what I tried I can't get the VerticalScrollBar to show up.

```
<Grid>
  <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignScrollViewer}">
     <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     </Grid>
   </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I need the Grid to be Stretched both Horizontally and Vertically so that it can dynamically resize itself.
I even tried setting the Height as `Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=ActualHeight}"` for both the Grid and ScrollViewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't enclose scroll viewer** inside another grid.

```
 <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignScrollViewer}">
     <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     </Grid>
   </ScrollViewer>
```